# How to add these checks in before Attacking?

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

So my issue is I can't seem to find/write in the correct xpath for "BV" & "enemyLevel"

BV meaning "Battle Value"

I've added a picture to show what I mean [image: enemyLevel + BV]

For you to test i've created a user & pass

Game: https://s9-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/user/login
user: testaccount123
pass: python123

I need it to only attack if enemyLevel <= 1, BV <=51

if not "search again"

my code that fails when it hits the page above

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\JC 
WIN10\\PycharmProjects\\BitefightPvpBOT\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("https://s9-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/user/login")  # SERVER LOGIN PAGE

driver.find_element_by_name("user").send_keys("testaccount123")  # USERNAME
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name("pass").send_keys("python123")  # PASSWORD
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-small").click()  # LOGIN BUTTON
time.sleep(1)

driver.get("https://s9-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/robbery/index") # HUNT PAGE
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name("optionsearch").click() # Werewolf Hunt
time.sleep(2)

BV = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(text(),'')]')
enemyLevel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'1')]")
print(enemyLevel.text, BV.text)

while enemyLevel <=1, BV <=51:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/div/div/button").click()  # ATTACK
    time.sleep(1)
    if enemyLevel >= 1, BV >=51:
    driver.find_element_by_name("optionsearch").click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check required values as

```
enemyLevel = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="Level:"]/following-sibling::td').text)
BV = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="Battle value:"]/following-sibling::td').text)

if enemyLevel <= 1 and BV =< 51:
    ...
else:
    # search for another victim
```

Comment: @JCSmyth Welcome. You can accept the answer if it solved your issue

Comment: There we go! do you have an email I can get in touch with you or discord username?

Comment: @JCSmyth , there is no need. Just tag your question with `Python` and `Selenium` and I will find your question :)